# what is good way to do merge the code in below scenarion (Git,Intellij,Stash)?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-stash

Git merging code

Let us say I have a branch called origin/develop , Everytime I work on a new feature I create a new branch from origin/develop as feature/feature_name
Let us say that I am working on the feature for a few days , I made some changes and also commited them to the remote feature/feature_name brach
Now Let us say that the origin/develop itself was changed meanwhile becuase some other developers commiting to it through pull requests.
If i create a pull request now to merge the code from feature/feature_name to origin/develop Stash does not like it.

I am using intellij idea to interact with Git , What is a clean way to get the changes that were made in origin/develop into my branch

Thanks

Comment: Intellij-idea has VCS plugin that you can use which will give you GUI with difference in the merge conflicts and gives you option to select your change or their changes

Answer (score 0):

## Clean way to merge changes

Create a branch from ***develop***

**Checkout** to **develop** branch

> git checkout develop

**get latest**, as many developers pushed their code to ***develop***

> git pull

**CreateBranch** from *develop*

> git checkout -b feature/test_feature

Push, worked for few days on the feature and push your changes to remote ***feature/test_feature*** branch

> git push -u origin feature/test_feature

### Merge changes from your branch to develop

We have two steps

**STEP 1:** Get latest from ***develop*** to ***feature/test_feature*** to test the your changes working with latest.

> git checkout develop
>
> git pull
>
> git checkout feature/test_feature
>
> git merge --no-ff origin develop

**Note: conflicts may occur if the other developer modified the same file that you modified at the same line**

**STEP 2:** Push your chnages from ***feature/test_feature*** to ***develop***

> git checkout develop
>
> git merge --no-ff origin feature/test_feature

DONE