# Git merge strategy for feature branches

Tags: git, merge, git-branch

I made a branch for a feature to keep the master branch clean. After I have now finished this feature I want to select the relevant commits and bring them back on top of the master. But as there are too many changes to do a regular merge I want to just use the changes made in the branch without actually merging them to the master. After studying the git documentation a couple of days and trying to find some answers elsewhere I now ask you how I could solve my problem.

Am I on the wrong way? Is there a better way of dealing with this issue?

What I want is to develop a feature in a separate branch and after completion just publish the relevant changes to the master branch. I could do this manually but I want to keep the changes documented within the VCS.

```
        --- ( feature branch ) --- E --- F --- G
       /            --------------/             \
      /            /                             \ 
A --- B --- C --- D ----------------------------- H --- I
```

Comment: Why not let git figure it out? What problem are you encountering?

Comment: [Related](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Using-git-to-prepare-your-PR-to-have-a-clean-history).

Comment: Thanks for the reading recommendation @AnsgarWiechers. It was a very revealing reading. The subject has become much clearer to me. I squashed some of the commits together and reordered others. Than I merged the cleaned up branch into the master.

I had probably thought in the wrong direction.

Comment: Here is the same answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46800881/what-is-good-way-to-do-merge-the-code-in-below-scenarion-git-intellij-stash/46802334#answer-46802334